Adding volume control between equalizer and power amp
I want to built an Equalizer preamp for my power amplifier(stk4141 II).The equalizer is "Rod Elliott (ESP)-Eight Band Sub-Woofer Graphic Equaliser".This circuit has input and output buffer with 8x MFB constant Q filters. Rod mentions that a "level control" can be added to the circuit.Can someone suggest me how to add a volume control to this circuit ?
link to Rod's project 84 : https://sound-au.com/project84.htm

A typical volume control is a potentiometer wired like:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The potentiometer value can vary, depending on circuit impedance.

For the best adjustment range, use a pot with an "audio taper".
